# Why is the copy assignment not deleted when the move assignment is declared?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-construction, copy-constructor, deleted-functions

```
struct A
{
    A(int x)
        : n(x)
    {}

    A(A&&)
    {}

    A& operator =(A&&)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    int n;
};

int main()
{
    A a(1), b(2);

    a = b;

    if (2 == a.n)
    {
        // It SHOULD go here!
    }
}
```

As per the C++ standard 12.8.7:

> If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment
>   operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as
>   deleted;

and 12.8.18

> If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment
>   operator, the implicitly declared copy assignment operator is defined
>   as deleted;

The statement `a = b;` should trigger a compiler error. However, my compiler (VC++ 2013 RC) accepts it and calls the implicitly-defined copy assignment instead.

Is this a compiler's bug?

**Update:**

I have submitted this issue as a bug to [microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/804896/the-copy-assignment-is-not-deleted-when-the-move-assignment-is-explicitly-declared#details).

Comment: "Is this a compiler's bug?" it wouldn't surprise me. MSVC handling of move ctors and move assignment op has always been lacking.

Comment: `a = b` wouldn't call the copy constructor, would it?

Comment: Isn't `a = b` a copy-assignment here? Your quote says the copy-constructor is deleted, not the copy-assignment operator.

Comment: @Useless, because the copy-assignment should have been deleted, so it will trigger an error.

Comment: @xmllmx why should the copy-assignment have been deleted? Either you posted the wrong quote, or read it wrong.

Comment: @xmllmx if there is a quote from the standard saying copy assignment is also deleted, you should include that too.

Comment: It does trigger a compilation error for `a=b` with GCC, looks like a bug in VC++ to me. The error message from GCC is `error: use of deleted function 'A& A::operator=(const A&)'` and `note: 'A& A::operator=(const A&)' is implicitly declared as deleted because 'A' declares a move constructor or move assignment operator`

Comment: @juanchopanza, my fault. I have added another quote.

Comment: Seeing as you have a user-provided move assignment operator, I believe that you're right. This shouldn't compile.

Comment: Could you please add more blank lines to your example, to make it more readable?

Comment: Couldn't the compiler see that there are no more uses of b in the function and optimize it to a move?

Comment: @RedX: The compiler generally can't just transform copies into moves except for some very specific circumstances. Standard C++ says that this is a copy so that's what it is and that is why it needs the copy-assignment-operator, even if for some reason the compiler actually could decide to omit using it (or compile it down to a nop). Having the compilability of code depend on the optimization capabilities of the compiler wouldn't be a good idea afterall.

Comment: @Grizzly Thanks for clarifying that, i always thought the compiler could do whatever it wanted under the 'as-if' rule.

Comment: @RedX The "as-if" rule states that the compiler can do whatever it wants - as long as it is does not change the semantics of the code. Calling the copy constructor instead of failing to compile doesn't fall under this, and so it isn't allowed.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a compiler bug indeed.

Since you have defined a user-provided move assignment operator, the copy assignment operator should be implicitly defined as deleted (as specified in 12.8.18). This is the behaviour exhibited by other compilers (gcc, for example).